# How to add days into [Today] SP 2010?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, custom-lists

How to add day in a customlist column with value 3 into another customlist column with [Today] in SharePoint 2010?

Example 
Customlist DayExp
 ExpireDay 3 ... /*I don't want to set the default calculate field into =[Today]+3 because it is fixed. I store in a Customlist column because I can edit the ExpireDay in the future to 1 or 2 or more days as I like.*/

Customlist KnowledgeSubmission
 SubmissionValidTo ... /*I want to add ExpireDay column value(3) with [Today] into this column*/

So how to add [Today] with ExpireDay value?

Javascript code function or just simple Onsave action in the form may be helpful as well.

Thank in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a list only calculates the values of a list when it is saved, you can never use the value of "Today" in a calculation (as it changes every second or so).

The default calculation of [Today] only happens when you are in the new form.
You could add some jQuery to the Editform.aspx and it is not too hard, but it may be easier to create a calculated field as:

```
=Modified+ExpireDay
```

Which will be whatever that date the item was saved + 2 days.

Comment: ok, thank for the response.
I am creating something like a forum. And Yes, every time a user open new form, the Published date is set by default as [Today].
But I don't want to set the calculated field by default with +2, because next time you need to edit the form again if maybe expired day is 3 or 4. I store the day(1,2..n) in a customlist because it is easy to edit.

Comment: Are you storing the days to expire in a field? I.e. =Modified+ExpireDays

Comment: yes, I am storing in a field.
I am using SQL now, SELECT (GETDATE() + ExpireDays)... and It works.
Thanks for your information and your method work as well!